# Can't login using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, correlation, load-testing

First of all, I am sorry for this much screenshots. But I am stuck with this for a long time. so, What I have done here is, I record a login in "Fiddler classic" and export it in JMeter. I am trying to login through JMeter. But it doesn't work. I couldn't record using blazemeter plugin or JMeter test script recorder that's why I have used Fiddler. In view results tree there is this same message every time "No connection with that ID".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7213.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtca2.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8l9z.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to [correlate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) the `id` parameter which is in the URL [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string):

[image]

So most probably if you replace it with `${var}` it will start working (assuming that `var` variable has valid value.

Try recording your test one more time and compare resulting JMeter .jmx test plans - all parameters which will differ are a subject to correlation.

More information: [How to Handle JMeter Correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)

Comment: I have just edited , I did correlate and it's giving me same result. Please have a look

Comment: Are you sure your HTTP Request 5 should really be [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request), shouldn't it be a [WebSocket](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers) one? Check request headers in the HTTP Header Manager and if there is [Upgrade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Upgrade) there - most probably you should switch the protocol.

Comment: You are right, There is an upgrade in request header. It says "Upgrade : websocket" , how should I change it?

Comment: 1. Install [WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager). 2. Add the relevant Sampler and configure it to establish the connection and/or send the [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) request which you have in Fiddler like it's described in the article I've referenced earlier.

Comment: Thank you, I installed Websocket Samplers, but as you realize It's not quite clear to me which websocket sampler I should use? And should I just replace HTTP request 5 with websocket sampler or all HTTP request needed to be replaced. One other thing is, if I use websocket sampler do I have to co-rrelate?